# AWS VPC endpoint IPV4 connection ot IPV6 Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

May some one help me to understand if AWS VPC endpoint for s3 is IPV4 of IPV6 connection? I have created a VPC with only IPV4 CIDR. I didn't provide any IPV6 CIDR.

When I create a route table entry for VPC endpoint I see the route only if I apply all rules. When I select IPV4 rules only it is not displayed. What does it mean? How is it working if case if vpc endpoint is not IPV4 connection?  Below screen shots for more reference.

IPV4 rules

All rules

Answer (score 0):

Currently, both Gateway Endpoints and Interface Endpoints support only IPv4 traffic (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html#vpc-endpoints-limitations).

Most likely, you are seeing only IPv4 prefixes because the prefix list (pl-xxxx) is considered to be in another category which, as of now, is not listed in the filtering options.